# Visual Studio 2013 only builds HTML changes, not C# changes

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, git, visual-studio

I am building a personal website using asp.NET's webforms in visual studio 2013 express for web and am following this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/introduction-and-overview

My page is structured exactly the same as in the website, I have changed some minor stuff to make it my own but the structure in terms of the C# classes and how the interact with the HTML are exactly the same.

I got to section 5 of the tutorial "Display Data Items and Details" and everything was working fine. I've used git a lot in the past so I decided to create a repository for this project so I can access it at work if I feel like.

Suddenly now when I make changes to the C# classes it won't build. It's even stranger because I if I make a change on an HTML file the change is built. In section 3 of the tutorial we learnt how to make the 'product' classes which are displayed on the products page. If I want to change one of the product names for example, when I build the change is not there. Simultaneously I went and changed some info in the HTML for the contact page, IT CHANGES when I build. Why wont the C# changes take effect when I build any more?

I am relatively new to both asp.NET and visual studio. The HTML changes when I build and the C# does not. When I change either I can see in solution explorer that there is a red tick for pending changes. Why would only the HTML pending change be included in the build and not the C#? How do I ensure that the build is actually building the version I see in my editor window?

***EDIT***

I do not know if I found the original cause but I found a solution/workaround. I realized that the classes mentioned above were grabbed by the html page from the page's database. The .mdf file for the solution was not being rebuilt whenever I cleaned and built so I physically deleted it and rebuilt the solution and voilla my C# changes occurred. I am still fairly new to this whole thing, can someone explain what the .mdf file does and why it wasn't being rebuilt?

Comment: What do you mean by "won't build"? What happens?

Comment: If you're just getting started, jump away from webforms and learn MVC. Slightly different paradigm, but [webforms are going away](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/24/top-10-changes-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6) very soon.

Comment: Tried to delete your bin and obj folders before you build?

Answer (score 1):

Check your .cs files properties on the properties window in visual studio to make sure their Build Action is set to "Compile", Things that are not set to "Compile" do not get compiled. How MSBuild treats project items depends entirely on their build action. CS files default to "Compile" when you make them, but if you changed them yourself that would be why it doesn't update. Also CS files placed in the App_Start folder default to "Content" and they are compiled by ASP.Net when the Application Starts, so if you changed something in App_Start you need to reset the site.

Comment: This was good advice but they were all set to 'Compile'. I found a solution/workaround which I described in my edit. Do you know why it worked @Ryios ?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what is the problem, but I would do a right mouse click on the solution in Solution Explorer->Clean Solution, then do another build and see if that helps.